# How to set maximum number of rows in one micro-batch?

Tags: apache-spark, redis, spark-structured-streaming

I am reading batch record from redis using spark-structured-streaming `foreachBatch` by following code (trying to set the batchSize by `stream.read.batch.size`)

```
val data = spark.readStream.format("redis")
  .option("stream.read.batch.size").load()

val query = data.writeStream.foreachBatch { 
  (batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) => ...
  // we count size of batchDF here, we want to limit its size
  // some operation
}
```

currently we set `stream.read.batch.size` to 128 but seems this does not work. The batchSize seems to be random, sometimes over 1000 even 10000.

However I do not want to wait for so long (10000 records) because I have some operations (in code comment `// some operation`) need to be done as soon as possible, so that I want to control the maximum batch size so when records reach this limitation it could be processed immediately, how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am a maintainer of spark-redis. This is currently not supported. The `stream.read.batch.size` parameter controls the number of items read by a single Redis API call (`count` parameter of XREADGROUP call). It doesn't affect the number of items per trigger (batchDF size). I have opened a ticket on github for this feature request.

Comment: Thanks, so according to you this is a spark-redis issue rather than spark-streaming issue. Could you kindly provide any materials that how spark-streaming get records from redis? Previously I though this is simply spark-behavior and seems I was wrong.

Comment: I though the api is on Spark side but now it seems on Redis side?

Comment: @Litchy, you may find the implementation of Strucutred Streamign source for Redis here https://github.com/RedisLabs/spark-redis/tree/master/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/redis/stream . The code that reads from Redis is here https://github.com/RedisLabs/spark-redis/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/redis/stream/RedisStreamReader.scala#L37

Comment: I found `count` parameter is actually the value we want to control, which is as I mentioned above, the size of each batch. Because the number of `count` we get from stream is the size of the `batchDF`, am I right?

Answer (score 1):

> we want to limit its size

You could use `Dataset.limit` for a streaming limit (at least in Spark 2.4.3).

With that, the code could look as follows:

```
val data = spark
  .readStream
  .format("redis")
  .load
  .limit(...your limit here...)
```

Comment: This works! but.... partly... Suppose we have 100 records in Redis and we use `.limit(5)`.  The first batch will take 5 records but the next batch will take 0...(The right behavior should be also 5, and third batch 5, ..., etc, and the 20th batch takes 5 and the 21st batch takes 0) Seems the `readStream` takes all the records from Redis so the index in Redis already changes to 100 and then it only takes the range(0,5) elements and the (5, 100) disappears...

Comment: And I tried another time, the first batch takes 1 and second takes 4, and no more third batch... Seems the overall streaming takes 5 (`.limit` parameter) in total. I guess my way calling it is wrong?

Comment: You use it correctly. `limit` gives you exactly the number of records you specify and there'll be as many micro-batches until the number is reached. If however you need a limit on the records per batch `limit` does not seem to a solution.

Comment: So seems the solution does not exist yet...? According to both of your answers.

Comment: The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56681567/1305344) is the one. I was answering a different use case.